# Why are TDD 'Spikes' called 'Spikes?

Tags: tdd, extreme-programming

The test driven development guys refer to a *quick, exploratory, investigation that involves coding something up to see if it works*, a **spike**.

Any ideas why they came up with that word?

**Update:** The coinage by Kent Beck looks like the 'original' one to me, although his usage of the word doesn't make much sense in my opinion. Coding up a quick test is 'putting a spike through the project'?

Interestingly, it seems he stopped using the term because it conjured up various meanings to different people - see below for evidence!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Ward Cunningham writes on [WardsWiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SpikeSolution) (referring to Kent Beck):

> I would often ask Kent, "What is the
>   simplest thing we can program that
>   will convince us we are on the right
>   track?" Such stepping outside the
>   difficulties at hand often led us to
>   simpler and more compelling solutions.
>   Kent dubbed this a Spike. I found the
>   practice particularly useful while
>   maintaining large frameworks.

Kent Beck writes in [Guide to Better Smalltalk](http://books.google.dk/books?id=Y7FwNB4GV4EC):

> Sometimes I call this a "spike," because we are driving a spike through the entire design. [...] Because people variously associate "spike" with volleyball, railroads, or dogs, I have begun using "architectural prototype" to describe this implementation.

Answer (score 11):

IMHO the term spike relates to driving a nail through a plank.
Yup.. here it is

> "Spike" is an Extreme Programming term
>   meaning "experiment". We use the word
>   because we think of a spike has a
>   quick, almost brute-force experiment
>   aimed at learning just one thing.
>   think of driving a big nail through a
>   board.
>   -- Extreme Programming Adventures in C# - Ron Jeffries

Answer (score 7):

I always considered it to be a mountain climber analogy.  Where you put a spike in the mountain on your way up.  If the spike sticks, then it's ok to go that way.

Comment: That's an interesting analogy and I like it, but most climbers would call them a piton, and pitons have been out of fashion on nearly every established climbing area for probably 30ish years (since the advent of camming devices). =P

Answer (score 2):

Because it's out of the ordinary, like a spike in a graph. E.g. A spike in CPU usage.

Answer (score 2):

The [Jargon File](http://www.elsewhere.org/jargon/jargon.html#spike) has the following entry:

**spike** v.

1. To defeat a selection mechanism by introducing a (sometimes temporary) device that forces a specific result. The word is used in several industries; telephone engineers refer to spiking a relay by inserting a pin to hold the relay in either the closed or open state, and railroaders refer to spiking a track switch so that it cannot be moved. In programming environments it normally refers to a temporary change, usually for testing purposes (as opposed to a permanent change, which would be called hardwired).
2. [borderline techspeak] A visible peak in an otherwise rather constant graph (e.g. a sudden surge in line voltage, an unexpected short "high" on a logical line in a circuit). Hackers frequently use this for a sudden short increase in some quantity such as system load or network traffic.

Answer (score 2):

It is called **Spiking** because it slices through all layers of the system. That's what he means when he says **Architectural Prototype**.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is an engineering expression. A spike is a temporary solution, something you try out to see if it works, before you make the permanent solution. Railroad engineers talk about *spiking a track switch*: inserting a rail spike into the switch, so it cannot be moved.